# How to call this endpoint in my Rest Assured Test case

Tags: rest-assured, get-request, rest-assured-jsonpath, geturl

Post request will generate the recordID like

{

}
I want to use the same ID in the below sample get request endpoint after ?recordId=

```
https://random-query-serv-poc-test-dummy.apps.dev-
```

How do I write a code to automate this GET Request?
I have written this code - but its not working as it is taking the request URI as below

```
SerenityRest.rest().given().
    header("header1", "ebc").
    header("header2", "svc").
    contentType(ContentType.JSON).
    log().all().
    when().


    then().log().all().
    assertThat().
    statusCode(200);
```

How can I send the request ID as it is converting the "/" as "%2F"

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your code, the problem might be the URL. You can test this in postman first.

Comment: Sure, Maybe I need to reframe the question , I haven't posted the actual endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can stop `auto URLencode` by [URL encoding config](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#url-encoding).

```
given().urlEncodingEnabled(false)
```